# Carbon Module Doesn't Exist in WSO2 Governance Registry 4.6.0

Tags: wso2, jaggery-js, wso2-governance-registry

I am attempting to create a Jaggery application for deployment on GREG 4.6.0.

However, when trying to interface with the Registry API, in accordance with the documentation, I notice that there isn't a Carbon module in the distributed .zip.

Is there another way to interface with the Registry?

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the future lookie-loos:

It looks as though it was left out. However, the 5.0.0 M4 release has it included.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in G-Reg 5 series. Kindly download the pack from [this](http://wso2.com/products/governance-registry/) location or kindly find the latest(dev) GREG version from [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-greg/releases).